# java.net.SocketPermission : "connect.resolve"

Tags: java, ldap, securitymanager

I'm in trouble with connecting Active Directory.
The codes in question is following:

```
Hashtable<Stirng,String> env = new Hashtable<String,String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"ldap://192.168.0.100:389");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"TEST\\Administrator");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"password");
LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
```

When I debug it, it gives me an error:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: 192.168.0.100:389 [Root Exception is java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "192.168.0.100:389" "connect.resolve")]
```

An IP I'm trying to connect is 192.168.0.99 (Windows 7)
192.168.0.100 is installed Windows 2008, and I double-checked that the connection doesn't have any problems when I try to connect from 192.168.0.100 itself.
Could you give me a piece of advice please?
I'm happy to provide more information if needed

Comment: Is your code running as an applet?

Comment: Start here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html

Comment: oh sorry. It's runing as an Servlet

Answer (score 2):

I found out what was wrong.
I added

```
grant
{
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:1024-65535","connect,accept,resolve";
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:1-1023","connect,resolve";
};
```

in policy file (which was catalina.policy for me)
Then, I added a statement in Arguments of Run configuration in eclipse as:

`-Djava.security.policy="c:\catalina.policy"`

Thanks

Comment: how to set this property in tomcat server -Djava.security.policy=="$CATALINA_BASE"/conf/catalina.policy