# org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2Acceptor.failed Socket accept failed - Tomcat 9.0.56

Tags: java, unix, tomcat9

I am getting some error from tomcat server using the security manager as shown below.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "<some ip address>:<some port>" "accept,resolve")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:886)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkAccept(SecurityManager.java:1167)
        at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl$1.run(UnixAsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl$1.run(UnixAsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl.java:219)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl.finishAccept(UnixAsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl.java:219)
        at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl.onEvent(UnixAsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl.java:167)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollPort$EventHandlerTask.run(EPollPort.java:293)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at sun.misc.InnocuousThread.run(InnocuousThread.java:106)
```

does anyone have any idea why this errors?

Comment: "<some ip address>:<some port>", Are these the real values?

Comment: no these are just place holders can't write the real ones

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393182/java-net-socketpermission-connect-resolve

Comment: do you know how  to set this propery -Djava.security.policy=="$CATALINA_BASE"/conf/catalina.policy in tomcat server